# OS X Terminal: "backward delete word" works only with C-M-h

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

Followup on [Mac OS X Terminal: Map option+delete to “backward delete word”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327664/mac-os-x-terminal-map-optiondelete-to-backward-delete-word?rq=1).

The `Use option key as meta key` option is checked, but the deleting word backwards works *only* with <kbd>^</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> (i.e. one has to *also* hold the <kbd>^</kbd> or `Control` key)! **How can you backward delete a word with <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> only?** This annoyance happens *only* in `Terminal.app` ... and interestingly also in `iTerm.app`!

I also have this in `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, so that I can enjoy Emacs throughout:

```
{"~h" = "deleteWordBackward:";}
```

---

Environment: OS X 10.8.2 (12C54), Terminal 2.3 (309), iTerm

Comment: On OS X 10.8.4, when I type Option-H with “Option is Meta” enabled, it sends “ESC h”. What program are you interacting with? Are you sure it maps “ESC h” to “backward delete word”? In many programs, you can verify what’s being sent to the tty by prefixing with either Control-V or Control-Q to quote the “ESC h” input.

Comment: For questions like this, it helps to include the OS version you’re working with.

Comment: @Chris Nice tip on using Control-V for inspection. Pressing "Option-H" sends "^[h" (either Option_L or Option_R).

Comment: Do you want to use Option + H or would Option + Delete be fine for the same purpose?

Comment: @MK Option + H, of course. Must stay on the home row. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings in DefaultKeyBinding.dict don't apply to the shell views in Terminal or iTerm 2.

You can make `M-h` delete a word backward by adding this to `~/.inputrc`

```
"\eh": backward-kill-word
```

`M-h` is bound to `mark-paragraph` by default in Emacs though.

If others search for how to make ⌥⌫ delete a word backward, just enable using option as a meta key:

- In Terminal, check Settings > (your profile) > Keyboard > Use option as meta key
- In iTerm 2, set the option keys to act as "+ Esc" in Profiles > (your profile) > Keys

If others search for how to make ⌥⌦ delete a word forward, you can make it insert `\ed`:

[image]
[image]

⌥⌦ inserts `\e(` by default in Terminal and `\e[3~` in iTerm 2, so you could also add `"\e(": kill-word` or `"\e[3~": kill-word` to `~/.inputrc`.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all terminal use emacs hotkeys to manipulate text (see [readline keyboard shortcuts](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts)), and in emacs, you use `backward-kill-word` (meta-delete) to delete the previous word.

And, in emacs, `meta-<KEY>` (key composition) equals to `escape <KEY>` (key chord), so in this case, you can use <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> <kbd>DEL</kbd> to delete the previous word.